# .NET Point.IsEmpty vs IsDefined

Tags: c#, system.drawing

In my UI class, a developer has the option to define a location property (type of System.Drawing.Point).  By default this property is initialized to Point.Empty.  The internal code that is encapsulated by the class uses the .IsEmpty of the Point property to determine if a location has been set.  If the property is not empty, the x/y value will be used.  If empty, the code will attempt to place it with a row/column algorythm.

My Issue:
I am using the .IsEmpty of the property to determine if it was set.  To my surprise, if a developer sets the property to 0,0 it came up as Empty.  A point of 0,0 is valid in graphics.  I also understand why the .IsEmpty returns true for the 0,0 value.

1) Without creating my own class or inheriting from System.Drawing.Point, is there a way to know if the property was set?

The only idea that I can think of is to default the property with a value of "new Point(-1,-1)" and test against that.  Is there a better way?  If not, please confirm.

I am using C# in Visual Studio 2005 and Visual Studio 2008

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a few ways:

1. Make the property a nullable Point, this way, it will be "null" when you haven't set it
2. Track whether anything has called the setter method by setting a private Boolean field to true

ie. either:

```
public Point? Location { ... }
```

or:

```
public Point Location
{
    get ...
    set
    {
        _LocationSet = true;
        _Location = value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Nullable types already have two properties "HasValue" and "Value" no need to define your own.

Comment: Yes I did and my point is that defining your own properties would be more hassle and add no real value over what the nullable type provides.  Stick with the nullable type.

Comment: It depends, with your own internal value like this, there would be no way to "unset" the value. It depends on what the person wants.

Comment: That's weak and just plain wrong.  Nullable type properties "HasValue" and "Value" are readonly.  Making your own is pointless.

Answer (score 2):

Keep the field as `Point?` (syntactic sugar for `Nullable<Point>`) instead of `Point`. That basically keeps track of whether the value is "real" one the null value. How you expose the property is up to you - you could expose it as `Point` and make it throw an exception if you try to fetch it without setting it, or you could expose it as `Point?` which would allow it to be "unset" by setting it to null again later.

Nullable value types are precisely designed for this sort of situation.

Comment: I tried the suggested change and I got the following errors...

'System.Nullable<System.Drawing.Point>' does not contain definition for 'X'.  The same is reported for 'Y', and 'IsEmpty'

Any ideas on what I am doing wrong?

Comment: You have to use "p.Value.X" because you are now using a nullable type.

Answer (score 1):

I might consider using a nullable Point:
System.Drawing.Point?
Nullable 
that would provide a cleaner path for knowing if something is set or not.