# c# null for System.drawing.PoinF

Tags: c#, nullable, system.drawing

I'm using C# for grphics. And now I want to return a null for PointF

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Project the point according to camera position.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="p">Point position, in WC</param>
    /// <returns>pixel position</returns>
    public PointF Project(MCvPoint3D32f p)
    {
        //return new PointF(p.x, p.y);
        // Extend p
        Matrix<double> p_ex = new Matrix<double>(3, 1);
        p_ex[0, 0] = p.x;
        p_ex[1, 0] = p.y;
        p_ex[2, 0] = p.z;

        var rst = HomographMatrix * p_ex;
        rst[0, 0] = rst[0,0] / rst[2, 0] * focalLength * scale;
        rst[1, 0] = rst[1, 0] / rst[2, 0] * focalLength * scale;

        return new PointF((float)rst[0, 0], (float)rst[1, 0]);
    }
```

Here I want to return a 'null' for the point if the point is out of FoV of my camera. But actually PointF is not 'nullable', so is there a straight forward way to return a 'null' for the point?

I don't want to inherit the native PointF.

Comment: Here is probably what You need : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1773232/net-point-isempty-vs-isdefined

Comment: "I don't want to inherit the native PointF." - you couldn't, anyway; `PointF` is a `struct` - you cannot inherit from a `struct`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In some ways this depends on your requirements. For example, if you need to store lots of points (so space is a factor), you could use some kind of sentinel value - perhaps:

```
static readonly PointF NilPoint = new PointF(float.NaN, float.NaN);
```

then check for that runtime, perhaps with a helper method:

```
public static bool IsNil(this PointF value)
{
    return float.IsNaN(value.X) || float.IsNaN(value.Y);
}
```

so you can just check:

```
if(!point.IsNil()) {
    // etc   
}
```

However, an easier option (with a slight space overhead) is just to use `Nullable<T>`, i.e.

```
PointF? pt1 = null; // fine
PointF? pt2 = new PointF(123,456); // also fine
```

Comment: +1 great answer. Mark, could you please give a simple note on how exactly Nullable will impact required storage for each note? We probably all know, that Nullable simply contains additional boolean as flag if value is set or not. But I guess there can be additional overheads to Nullable.

Comment: I'll take this answer. I don't really care about the space in this scenario. If I do, I'll rewrite my code in c++. However, same with @IlyaIvanov, I'm also looking forward to your update on the overheads.

Comment: @IlyaIvanov padding means that the `bool` (theoretically 1 bit of information) is probably going to take 4 bytes

Answer (score 2):

Use [System.Nullable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h38hb0.aspx):

```
public PointF? Project(MCvPoint3D32f p)
{ 
   // other code here

   if (condition)
     return null;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Just use System.drawing.PointF.Empty

Comment: Well, empty point is just a point with `x = 0` and `y = 0`. What to do if you want to return real point with such coordinates? `new PointF() == PointF.Empty` this code returns true.

Comment: The question is fine; this answer, however, is simply wrong - as Ilya notes, there is no way to distinguish `PointF.Empty` from either `new PointF()` or `new PointF(0,0)` - and zero/zero is usually a perfectly fine and reasonable location (the origin), so can't be treated as a "null" value.

Comment: Yeah, thanks for your correction. I didn't realize that PointF.Empty == new PointF();